# Interesting electric shock question

Tags: electricity

So the other day I was moving a fan and I put my hand on the wire. I got an electric shock for about 5 seconds, whilst being thrown over the sofa. Now I touched it with bare dry hands, and I had bare feet that were both touching a laminated dry floor at the time. The appliance as seen in the photo states that it’s 230v and 170w power. What would the ampere have been that went through my body as an estimate?[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to replace the photo with one that's cropped.

Comment: This is something that can vary widely.  A more effective heuristic would be to look at what the effect of this shock was on the body and reference that against a chart of what effects are felt at different currents like [this one on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_injury#Lethality)

Comment: *"I put my hand on the wire"* Which wire are you talking about? BTW, you need to dispose of this fan. (A competent electrician *may* be able to repair it, but a new fan is probably cheaper).